# How can I set the umask from within java?

Tags: java, file-permissions

I'm new to Java. Where is umask exposed in the api?

Answer (score 13):

You can't fiddle with the umask directly, since Java is an abstraction and the umask is POSIX-implementation specific. But you have the following API:

```
File f;
f.setExecutable(true);
f.setReadable(false);
f.setWritable(true);
```

There are some more APIs available, [check the docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

If you *must* have direct access to the umask, either do it via JNI and the `chmod()` syscall, or spawn a new process with `exec("chmod")`.

Comment: Hm interesting, thanks. I guess I can use JNI to call umask(2), then?

Comment: @eeee sure, but you'd have to deploy your JNI module to all platforms you want to support, as it's almost by definition platform dependent.

Comment: @extraneon yes, of course. To be honest I'm very surprised that no one has made a module for Java exposing all the posix interfaces. I mean, that can't be right -- right? How do people perform system activities in java without this kind of thing?

Comment: @eeee New APIs for this are coming in Java 7 (which is not out yet), in the package `java.nio.file`.

Comment: to be precise: in the package `java.nio.file.attribute`.

Comment: @eeee what's wrong with exec("chmod 777 yourfilename")?  Or is the code section doing this extremely performance critical?

Comment: @eeee even before java 7, sun(oracle) released a library called JNA that allows you to directly call into any native code including glibc. With it, they also have a prebuilt wrapper around all posix functions. And JNA supports any platform that is known to run a JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a 3rd-party Java library that exposes POSIX system calls; e.g.

- [Jtux](http://basepath.com/aup/jtux/)
- The ["Posix for Java"](http://www.bmsi.com/java/posix/index.html) library,
- and so on (Google for "java posix library").

The problem with this approach is that it is intrinsically non-portable (won't work on a non-POSIX compliant platform), and requires a platform-specific native library ... and all that that entails.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission

File file = new File("/some/path") 
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath(), [
                PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ,
                PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE
            ].toSet())
```

Comment: No, that's setting the permissions on a file, not setting the mask.

Answer (score 0):

`java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFileAttributes` in Java SE 7.

Comment: I didn't not find any functions there for setting the umask specifically, only file permissions.