# Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE permission to FileOutputStream(file,append) without context.openFileOutput

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to add `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE permission to FileOutputStream(file,append)` which is only possible in `context.openFileOutput(name,Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE)` but i dont need openFileOutput since I am not able to make sub directories and also i need append mode `true`.

What can i do???

Thanks In Advance

Comment: have you tried using FileWriter methods.. ??

Comment: yes i m using FileWriters while writing but thats not affecting my Readable Mode

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using openFileOutput / openFileInput You can access file /directories from internal storage of application sandbox by path like /data/data/(package name) and on this path you can do anything will able to crate directory or files. Also in this scenario you will able to use files writable modes.

Comment: can u show me how can i do that??? coz i could not find any method where i can use Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE..except openFileOutput

Comment: /data/data/(package name) i dont want path like this but sub paths...like /data/data/folder/subfolder

Comment: File file=new File("/data/data/com.example/newfile.txt");
  try {
   file.createNewFile();
   
   FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file, true); //true will be open file in appended mode
   out.write("My data".getBytes());
  
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(file); For file reading input stream is used and input stram is only supported with reading thats y it has no mode. You can use writable/append permission while writing file. It will not supported for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use FileOutputStream as usual, then close it, then call File.setReadable.

Take a look here for more details: [java set file permissions to 777 while creating a file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233541/java-set-file-permissions-to-777-while-creating-a-file-object)