# Java NIO FIle path Issue 2

Tags: java, windows, file, permissions, nio

I am trying to view all the File permissions of a file through Java. For that I am using Java 1.7 and using `Java.nio.Files`

The code is:

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/drusia/Desktop/TestDir/Dell.txt");

PosixFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(paths,  PosixFileAttributes.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
Set <PosixFilePermission> permissions = attrs.permissions ();
System.out.println (PosixFilePermissions.toString (permissions));
```

But I get an error of

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.comparator.Prac.main(Prac.java:29)
```

The same program works on Ubuntu very well (of course the file path is changed to an existing Unix Directory) and all details are given. But this does not work on Windows.

Can someone help me with this?

The import statements are:-

```
      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.nio.file.Files;
      import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
      import java.nio.file.Path;
      import java.nio.file.Paths;
      import java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute;
      import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFileAttributes;
      import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
      import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions;
```

Comment: hope this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415960/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-posixpermissions-not-supported-as-in

Comment: Can you post the import statements?