# Clojure Boot error on windows 'posix:permissions'

Tags: java, clojure

I am trying to run boot on windows, but every time I start a build, it blows up the following error:

```
                                                      Boot.main                       Boot.java: 258
                                                        ...
                                              boot.App.main                        App.java: 491
                                           boot.App.runBoot                        App.java: 399
org.projectodd.shimdandy.impl.ClojureRuntimeShimImpl.invoke     ClojureRuntimeShimImpl.java: 150
org.projectodd.shimdandy.impl.ClojureRuntimeShimImpl.invoke     ClojureRuntimeShimImpl.java: 159
                                                        ...
                                            boot.main/-main                        main.clj: 202
                                          boot.file/tmpfile                        file.clj: 136
                         java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile                      Files.java: 897
                java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile             TempFileHelper.java: 161
                        java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create             TempFileHelper.java: 138
                             java.nio.file.Files.createFile                      Files.java: 632
                         java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel                      Files.java: 361
        sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel  WindowsFileSystemProvider.java: 222
         sun.nio.fs.WindowsSecurityDescriptor.fromAttribute  WindowsSecurityDescriptor.java: 358
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'posix:permissions' not supported as initial attribute
```

My build.boot file is as follows:

```
(set-env!

  :target-path "target/"

  :source-paths #{"src/java"}
  :resource-paths #{"src/clj"}

  :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [http-kit "2.1.18"]
                 [ring/ring-codec "1.0.1"]
                 [expectations "2.0.9"]
                 [slingshot "0.12.2"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                 [cheshire "5.5.0"]]

  :dev-dependencies '[[junit/junit "4.12"]])

(task-options!
  pom {:project 'my-project
       :version "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"}

  aot {:namespace '[my-project.core]}

  jar {:manifest {}})

(deftask build "build project" []
         (comp (aot)
               (javac)
               (uber)
               (jar)
               (target "target/")))
```

This build works perfectly on ubuntu, so I think I am missing something necessary to run boot on windows.

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415960/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-posixpermissions-not-supported-as-in) that this is related to some call to the createFile method in the java File class, but since this call is made by boot, I think I might be missing some configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem today on 2.7.0 version of boot. 2.6.0 version doesn't have such problem.