# How to make CharSink respect file permissions?

Tags: java, file, guice, file-permissions

I would expect exception to be thrown in this code at line: `charSink.write("hi world");`  since the file is set to be non writable. But this code executes without any exceptions. How to make CharSink respect file permissions?

```
public class CharSinkWritingNonWritableFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final File file = getNewFile();

        file.setWritable(false, false);

        val charSink = Files.asCharSink(file, Charsets.UTF_8, FileWriteMode.APPEND);

        file.setWritable(false, false);
        
        charSink.write("hi world");

        Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8).forEach(line -> {
            System.out.println(line);
        });

    }

    private static File getNewFile() {

        final File file = new File("/tmp/hi-world");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        return file;
    }
}
```

Edit:

OS: MacOS 12.4

Comment: which os are you using, windows ? setExecutable alse false and check this answer please. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14415997/2165146

Comment: What's the value returned from `file.setWritable(false, false);`?  [That will return `false` if the call fails](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable(boolean,%20boolean)).

Comment: Additionally, metadata doesn't always sync instantly, so it might be possible to finish a write before the changes are prevented.