# How can I set OTHERS_WRITE when creating a file?

Tags: java, clojure, java.nio.file

I am attempting to use [createFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) with a FileAttribute derived from `"rw-rw-rw-"`. My file is being created as `"rw-rw-r--"` on Fedora.

How can I set OTHERS_WRITE when creating a file?

Example:

```
(->> "rw-rw-rw-"
     PosixFilePermissions/fromString
     PosixFilePermissions/asFileAttribute
     vector
     into-array
     (Files/createFile (Paths/get "temp" (into-array String []))))
;;; temp is created as rw-rw-r--
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In unix like systems every process has a property called [umask](http://linuxaria.com/article/linux-shell-understanding-umask-with-examples) which is masked onto the permissions of any file created and inherited by child processes. the default is `0002` or "turn off write for others". So it's most likely that **Java is setting the permission you seek and then it's being masked out**. You can explicitly set the permissions [after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233541/java-set-file-permissions-to-777-while-creating-a-file-object) creating the file or change the umask settings of the java process *before* you start it.

First lets look at the current umask:

```
arthur@a:/tmp$ umask
0002
```

then lets make a file with read and write for everyone (touch does this as well as your java code)

```
arthur@a:/tmp$ touch foo
arthur@a:/tmp$ ls -l foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arthur arthur 0 Aug 28 13:58 foo
```

we see that the octal `0002` has been masked out of the actual file permissions.
So we can remove this umask by setting it to 0000:

```
arthur@a:/tmp$ umask 0000
arthur@a:/tmp$ touch foo
```

And we see that foo remains as it was when updating because umasks only apply to *new* files. and a new file bar is created with the read-other permission.

```
arthur@a:/tmp$ ls -l foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arthur arthur 0 Aug 28 14:00 foo
arthur@a:/tmp$ touch bar
arthur@a:/tmp$ ls -l bar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 arthur arthur 0 Aug 28 14:00 bar
```

I'm in the habit of setting permissions explicitly after creating a file in Java because this carries more easily from system to system* You can prove this to your self by setting the umask in your shell before you run emacs/your-program and checking the file permissions after.

*Java is "write once run anywhere" eh?