# Set file permission in java 5

Tags: linux, jsp, file-permissions, java-5

I am using the below code to upload image. The problem is that after uploading the image i cant change the file permission. my file permission set by default is `rw-r--r--` (`0644`). Is it possible to change the file permission or set it as `0777` by default? It works fine in my local system. But not able to change the permission in my linux server.

```
    <%
    try

    {

        int filesize=0;
        String fieldname="",fieldvalue="",filename="",content="",bookid="",bkdescription="";        

        try {
            List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            for (FileItem item : items) {
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                    fieldvalue = item.getString();                 
                    if(fieldname.equals("homeid")){
                        bookid=fieldvalue;
                    }

                    if(fieldname.equals("bkdescription")){
                        bkdescription=fieldvalue;
                    }             

                } else {
                    try{
                    fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                    filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                    InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
                    filesize=(int)item.getSize();
                    filename="literal_"+bookid+".jpg";
                    if(filesize>0){                     
                    byte[] b=new byte[filesize];                  
                    int c=0;                                   

                    File f=new File(getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/imagesX");
    String filePah=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/imagesX";

                    if(f.isDirectory())
                    {
                        String fl[]=f.list();
                        for(int i=0;i<fl.length;i++)

                            {

              File fd=new File(getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/imagesX/"+fl[i]);
                             if(fd.getName().equals(filename))
                             fd.delete();

                        }

                    }

                    if(!f.exists())
    {
            new File(filePah).mkdir();      
f.mkdir()
    }                

   java.io.FileOutputStream fout=new java.io.FileOutputStream(getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/imagesX/"+filename);    

                    while((c = filecontent.read(b)) != -1 )
                    {
                        fout.write(b, 0, c);

                    }

                    fout.close();
                    filecontent.close();
                    }

                    }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in creation of file      :"+e);

                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
        }

    }

    catch(Exception exp)

    {
        out.println(exp);
    }

    %>
```

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3175320/324900

Comment: thanks, I ws looking this for a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the file permission from inside java code.

Your system's default umask is set to `0644` for new file. It wouldn't be good idea to change the default umask.

What you need is to do is set the permission of your directory to `0777` and then redefine your directory's `ACL` to recursive, so all new file created inside will inherit the same permission.

Heres a link which shows how to go about -
https://superuser.com/questions/151911/how-to-make-new-file-permission-inherit-from-the-parent-directory

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to change the permissions externally with a system command, chmod.

Example:

```
public static void runCmd (String[] cmd) {

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader (
                p.getInputStream()
            )
        );
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}

    runCmd(new String[] {
        "/bin/chmod",
        "755",
        "/path/to/your/script"
    });
```

P.S. were you also trying to call Java from a stored proc in an Oracle database?