# set execute permition on file

Tags: java, linux

I need to set execute permition on Linux script file using java 1.4. I would prefer to use java native library. If it is not possible with native library what is lightweight lib that allows to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`JAVA5`** and prior there is workaround using `exec` extracted [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24250239/3850595):

```
public static void runCmd (String[] cmd) {

    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader (
                p.getInputStream()
            )
        );
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

**USE**

```
runCmd(new String[] {
    "/bin/chmod",
    "755",
    "/path/to/your/script"
});
```

[By terminal in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/151911/how-to-make-new-file-permission-inherit-from-the-parent-directory)

**UP TO `JAVA6`**
For permissions use [`File::setExecutable(boolean [, boolean])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable%28boolean,%20boolean%29)

```
File file = new File("/your/path/to/file/file_script.sh");
file.setExecutable(true);
```

Check this [MKYONG permissions tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-the-file-permission-in-java/)

Comment: Does it work for Java versions prior 1.6?

Comment: Yes in `Java6`, not in `Java5`. But [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095728/set-file-permission-in-java-5) you can find a workaround for `Java5`

Comment: The probvlem is, that version is 1.4 for this question, not even 1.5

Comment: Both are right.... havn't seen that. I updated my answer