# How to set 777 permission on a folder structure in Linux from Java?

Tags: java, linux, directory-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i programmatically change file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)
>   [How can I set the umask from within java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175303/how-can-i-set-the-umask-from-within-java)

In *Linux*, I am trying to give full permission (777) to a folder structure (say ex: "home/test/sample/") for creating a *MySQL* table with changing the data directory to the user specific location from my application which is written in *Java*.

How can I give full permission to a folder structure from *Java*?

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664432/how-do-i-programmatically-change-file-permissions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a Operating System dependent code just like this:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc;
    int exitVal = -1;
    try {
        proc =  rt.exec("chmod 777 "+file);
        exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Try based on the above code, after executing this, Iam trying to create mysql table, it shows error like this :                                                                 ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/test/Sample/test1/sample.MYD' (Errcode: 13)                                                                                                                                      (The specified directory now gain full permission. But table couldnot be created)

Comment: check the owner and group permission for that newwly created dir.