# Write file with camel and set chmod

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, chmod

The camel FTP component allows to **set chmod** property (see [Apache Camel: FTP2](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html)) on stored files.
Is there a way to do the same with the **camel file component** ?

Something like `from("somewhere").to("file:foo.txt?chmod=666")`.

If not, do you know a *nice way* to do that with camel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions in FTP is pretty straight forward with chmod style. Permisson on files are not really as simple (with all file systems and OS implementations out there). To my knowledge, there is nothing like that directly in the Camel file endpoint.

But, if you know the deployment platform, you can use the [exec component](http://camel.apache.org/exec.html) to make a call to, say `chmod 666 myfile.txt` after it has been created, either in the route or in a route policy. There are some ways directly in java, but there is no golden way to do this, at least not platform independent. Look at this SO [How can I set the umask from within java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175303/how-can-i-set-the-umask-from-within-java).

Comment: I created my files directly in Java, it works fine. I would rather do that in Camel, but I will wait a next version.

Comment: I logged a ticket to see if we can improved on this in Camel - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6099